# Multiple buttons to control bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm working on a bootstrap/wordpress site built by someone else.
The changes I am making are on a customer booking page, which has an accordion form to put the user details in, after they have selected the product information. The change I am making means there is now 2 buttons `email` and `call`. When the user clicks either one of these the validation script runs on the product info, then the contact details accordion should open. If the `email` button is selected then the `call` button then the form needs to stay open, and only close is the same (active) button is clicked again.

Problem I have is that the current accordion system opens before the validation script is finished, and if I try to call the collapse function after the validation script by using a function rather then the original accordion system `$(this).collapse('toggle');` I get an error saying the function doesn't exist.
I have no idea how to make this work

```
<div>
    <a class="btn-email" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#booking" href="#body-four" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="body-four" onclick="$( '#promo' ).removeClass( 'flip-container-two flip-container-three flip-container-four');$( '#promo' ).addClass( 'flip-container-four');" href="#">Email</a>
</div>  

<div>
    <a class="btn-call" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#booking" href="#body-four" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="body-four" onclick="$( '#promo' ).removeClass( 'flip-container-two flip-container-three flip-container-four');$( '#promo' ).addClass( 'flip-container-four');" href="#">Call Back</a>
</div>

<div id="body-four" class="collapse closed" aria-labelledby="heading-four">
    ...
</div>
```

I need to be able to click one of the buttons and run a function that  which I can activate the collapse within

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Comment: Sorry should have done already

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have a function called `collapse()` but some extensions of it do. However, that's not how Bootstrap works. Bootstrap is using the `data-toggle` attribute as internal working memory. Pressing the accordion button, in a normal use case, might simply add or remove the `closed` property from the `data-toggle` attribute, or it may run some other scripts attached to that button. However, you can try, in your console first, simply removing the `closed` property to see if that gives you the desired effect. If it does, then you can use the jQuery `$(this).attr("data-toggle", "closed");`, assuming that you've selected the element and captured its click event properly.